# Is there a way to include the useragent in the error log?

Tags: python, flask

I have Flask setup to email me when an error occurs but I'd like to include the UserAgent in that email. Is that possible? I didn't see it in [The docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/errorhandling/#logformat).

EDIT: The link says more stuff can be found in the official documentation but isn't that the official documentation? ([flask.readthedocs.org](http://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/errorhandling/) says the same thing)

Comment: maybe a duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878020/how-do-i-get-the-user-agent-with-flask

Comment: @xbb: I saw that but my question is more specific: how do I include the UserAgent in the error email (or even how do I access the request object for the error email)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered how to do this deep in [this article](http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/python-web-applications-with-flask-part-iii/#.U2U4l61dVig). You'll need to set up a new filter to add the user-agent to the record. It seems that at filter stage, you can use the request object to get at what you're looking for. So you're not actually filtering anything out, but adding more to the log record. Functional example:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

if not app.debug:
    import logging
    from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler

    class ContextualFilter(logging.Filter):
        def filter(self, log_record):
            log_record.user_agent = request.user_agent
            return True

    context_provider = ContextualFilter()
    app.logger.addFilter(context_provider)
    mail_handler = SMTPHandler('127.0.0.1', 'apperror@example.com',
                    app.config['ADMINS'], 'Application failed')
    mail_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("""
Message type:       %(levelname)s
Location:           %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d
Module:             %(module)s
Function:           %(funcName)s
Time:               %(asctime)s
User-Agent:         %(user_agent)s

Message:

%(message)s
"""))
    mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
```

Using this, I was able to get emails sent to myself for error logs.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer was one click away in the docs. Check out [this entry](http://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/errorhandling/#logformat) on custom email message formatting. Use the example code snipped, adding an import of the Flask `request` object. Get the string itself using methods from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878020/how-do-i-get-the-user-agent-with-flask).

```
from logging import Formatter
from flask import request
mail_handler.setFormatter(Formatter('''
Message type:       %(levelname)s
Location:           %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d
Module:             %(module)s
Function:           %(funcName)s
Time:               %(asctime)s
UserAgent:          %s

Message:

%(message)s
''' % flask.request.user_agent.string))
```

This may not be perfect (especially my string formatting code) but hopefully that article points you in the right direction.

Comment: I get an error: RuntimeError: working outside of request context

Comment: Interesting, you must not have access to the app global variables by the time you are creating the log record. You will be able to get at any of [these](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord) attributes of the `LogRecord` class at a minimum. I'll have to keep digging to see if there is a way to get at the global context variables at the stage where the mail_handler is set.