# How to get http headers in flask?

Tags: python, http, flask, http-headers, authorization

Using Flask, how can I read HTTP headers? I want to check the authorization header which is sent by the client.

Comment: Related: [How do I get the user agent with Flask?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9878020)

Comment: Also, see the [*Flask Quickstart*](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object) and [*API documentation*](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#incoming-request-data).

Answer (score 487, accepted):

```
from flask import request
request.headers.get('your-header-name')
```

`request.headers` behaves like a dictionary, so you can also get your header like you would with any dictionary:

```
request.headers['your-header-name']
```

Comment: FYI: I'm looking at http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/ and it appears you could also access the username and password for basic authentication like so: `request.authorization.username` or `request.authorization.password`.

Comment: @Karthic Raghupathi, as long as the header doesn't have illegal characters like dashes, which most headers do (i.e., X-Api-Key), in which case you need to access it like a dictionary with keys.

Comment: Adding `if hasattr(request, 'authorization'):` to code will help check for missing 'authorization' attribute in request.

Comment: @Abhijeet: It seems this isn't always the case. When I use `curl` without specifying authorisation headers, `hasattr(request, 'authorization')` returns `True` but `getattr(request, 'authorization')` returns `None`. I'm not sure if this is the result of middleware or frameworks I'm using (Flask-Restful, for example).

Comment: @MichaelScheper may using `in` operator check might help, it worked for me `if 'authorization' in request:`, [other usage of in operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11447648/452708)

Comment: @Abhijeet: Again, that checks whether the key exists, but not whether the value exists. A safer way would be `if request.headers.get('your-header-name', None)`—this will pass only if 'your-header-name' exists _and_ the value is non-null.

Comment: @MichaelScheper that's a fact, the logic needs to have few conditional together to take-care of `Non-Existence & None value` i.e., `if 'headers' in request and request.header is not None and 'authorization' in request.headers and request.headers['authorization'] is not None:`

Comment: @Abhijeet: ... or you could just use the code that I suggested in my previous comment. Much cleaner.

Comment: Flask headers are not a dict, yeah?... i see them coming back as werkzeug.datastructures.EnvironHeaders in my tests. 
 http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.EnvironHeaders

Comment: @MichaelScheper the second argument to `get` would seem to be redundant, since I believe `None` is the default.

Comment: @holdenweb: Thanks—you're right. I thought the second parameter was necessary to prevent a `KeyError`, but that's only true for `request.headers['your-header-name']`. (I should've known that.) But it's been a while since I've looked at this, so I'm not sure if that resolves Abhijeet's and Pandem1c's concerns.

Comment: Me neither - just adding another acorn to your store of knowledge.

Answer (score 43):

If any one's trying to fetch all headers that were passed then just simply use:

```
dict(request.headers)
```

it gives you all the headers in a dict from which you can actually do whatever ops you want to. In my use case I had to forward all headers to another API since the python API was a proxy

Comment: @JamieLindsey This is not true.  `request.headers` is actually an `EnvironHeaders` object that can be accessed like a dictionary.

https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.EnvironHeaders

Comment: Although @jasonrhass is correct in most cases, `EnvironHeaders` isn't a subclass of `dict` so it fails many times where a `dict` would succeed (`isinstance(flask.request.headers, dict) == False`).  For example, the following code produces an error: `print(json.dumps(flask.request.headers, indent=4))`.  The fix is `print(json.dumps(dict(flask.request.headers), indent=4))`.

Comment: @TimLudwinski You're maybe missing out on the context. There was a deleted comment which claimed that the `request.headers` would be of type `dict` since it can be accessed/queried like a `dict`. The comment you see, is a response to that.

Answer (score 39):

just note, The different between the methods are, if the header is not exist

```
request.headers.get('your-header-name')
```

will return `None` or no exception, so you can use it like

```
if request.headers.get('your-header-name'):
    ....
```

but the following will throw an error

```
if request.headers['your-header-name'] # KeyError: 'your-header-name'
    ....
```

You can handle it by

```
if 'your-header-name' in request.headers:
   customHeader = request.headers['your-header-name']
   ....
```

Comment: well it's a default Python's mapping-classes behaviour

Answer (score 11):

Let's see how we get the params, headers, and body in Flask.
I'm gonna explain with the help of **Postman**.

[image]

The params keys and values are reflected in the API endpoint.
for example **key1** and **key2** in the endpoint :
`https://127.0.0.1/upload?key1=value1&key2=value2`

```py
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/upload')
def upload():

    key_1 = request.args.get('key1')
    key_2 = request.args.get('key2')
    print(key_1)
    #--> value1
    print(key_2)
    #--> value2
```

After params, let's now see how to get the **headers**:

[image]

```py
header_1 = request.headers.get('header1')
header_2 = request.headers.get('header2')
print(header_1)
#--> header_value1
print(header_2)
#--> header_value2
```

Now let's see how to get the **body**

[image]

```py
file_name = request.files['file'].filename
ref_id = request.form['referenceId']
print(ref_id)
#--> WWB9838yb3r47484
```

so we fetch the uploaded files with `request.files` and text with `request.form`

Comment: What's the program in the screenshots?

Comment: @LUNA that is Postman - https://www.postman.com/

Comment: Awesome thank you!