# Extract Field Headers from Blob Handler in Flask on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, http-headers

I am trying to parse the `POST` request sent by the App Engine blobstore handler in development to get the Google Cloud Storage file path (`'/gs/...'`) using Flask. Webapp2 has a method to get this if you inherit from `blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler` :- `self.get_file_infos()`. This method is not available in Flask.

This is a sample of the raw request data in Flask using `request.get_data()`:

```
--===============0287937837666164318==
Content-Type: message/external-body; blob-key="encoded_gs_file:ZnBscy1kZXYvZmFrZS1nVTFHNFdrc3hobUFoaEtWVEVmNHZnPT0="; access-type="X-AppEngine-BlobKey"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Human Code Reviews One.pdf"

Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 951486
Content-MD5: NzNhOTI0YjdjNTFiMjEyYmY0NDUzZGFmYzBlOTExNTY=
X-AppEngine-Cloud-Storage-Object: /gs/appname/fake-gU1G4WksxhmAhhKVTEf4vg==
content-disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Human Code Reviews One.pdf"
X-AppEngine-Upload-Creation: 2018-01-22 12:26:08.095166


--===============0287937837666164318==--
```

I have tried both `msg = email.parser.Parser().parsestr(raw_data)` and `msg = email.message_from_string(raw_data)` but `msg.items()` return an empty list.

If I do `rd = raw_data.split('\r\n')` and parse a line containing a proper header I get what I want for that line: `[('X-AppEngine-Cloud-Storage-Object', '/gs/appname/fake-gU1G4WksxhmAhhKVTEf4vg==')]`.

The issue is how to do this for the entire string and skip the blank and boundary lines.

For now, I am using the following code but I can't help but think there's a way to do this without reinventing the wheel:

```
for line in raw_data.split('\r\n'):
    if line.startswith(blobstore.CLOUD_STORAGE_OBJECT_HEADER):
        gcs_path = line.split(':')[1].strip()
```

Thank you.

**Edit:**

This question is not a duplicate of the one [here (How to get http headers in flask?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386995/how-to-get-http-headers-in-flask) because I have a raw string (called a *field* header, see the boundary delimiters not present in HTTP headers) I would like to parse into a dictionary.