# Can't access request in python flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to access request headers when a user visits a particular page. It is a cron function and according to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml). I should be able to identify if the request comes from the Service Account by checking for header X-Appengine-Cron. I've tried this and have been using request throughout my application with no problems however for this it returns the error:

```
local variable 'request' referenced before assignment
```

I have tried replicating other functions which utilise request however there is no issue there. I am using a very basic test to check it is working:

```
from flask import (
    Blueprint, Flask, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
)

@app.route('/cloud-datastore-export', methods = ['GET'])
def cloud_datastore_export():
  test = request.headers.get('X-Appengine-Cron')
```

I expect test to contain X-Appengine-Cron value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get http headers in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386995/how-to-get-http-headers-in-flask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message:

> `local variable 'request' referenced before assignment`

is a good suggestion. Indeed, you did not define request anywhere in your code.

**request** property is "injected" under the hood by Flask when you decorate a method with `@app.route`.

Hence:

*You will be able to access request properly only from within methods decorated with `@app.route` where **app** is an instance of flask.Flask class.*

For example:

```py
from flask import Flask

# (some code here)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/path/to/this/method')
def my_handler():
    headers = request.headers
    # (some more logic here)
```

Comment: Apologies updated my code. I do indeed have the code within the app decorator.

Comment: @user3385136 and how do you define `app`?