# Permission error for Azure Active Directory easy auth /.auth/me returns 401

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I've a Python Flask App for which I've use Azure Easy Auth (Azure Active Directory)for App Service. The login mechanism works well. However I want the info of who the logged in user is i.e., name, email etc. For this I understood that we can call http://xyz.contoso.com/.auth/me which will return the data required. However, when I send a get request from the Web App, it does not work and **returns a 401 with you do not have permission to view this directory or page**. If I browse to the same page with my browser, it works returning the data about the logged in user. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Please add your code for us to do further investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access http://xyz.contoso.com/.auth/me via browser since you have authenticated session. But if you send the get request from the web app, you will have no permission.

However, you can get the user information from the headers. App Service passes user claims to your application by using special headers. External requests aren't allowed to set these headers, so they are present only if set by App Service. Some example headers include:

**X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME**

**X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID**

Reference:

[Access user claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims)

Comment: Thanks Tony Ju. I think I understand this. But where does my app receive these headers. I was looking into the browser inspect tools but could not find these. How can I extract these headers. Mine is a Python-Flask app. I just got started on this stuff. Thanks again.

Comment: @Vijay You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386995/how-to-get-http-headers-in-flask

Comment: @Vijay were you able to solve this? I am having the same issue with 401 status in my Node.js based Azure App Service app. I am also unable to find the headers via the browser's inspect tools or using the request headers dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `.auth/me` endpoint within your app (e.g. flask) if you add the appropriate header to your request.

Here is an example:

```py
from typing import Dict

import httpx
from httpx import Response

url: str = "https://some_url/.auth/me"

cookie_header: str = "AppServiceAuthSession"
cookie_value: str = "{cookie_value}"

cookie_value: str = f"{cookie_header}={cookie_value}"

headers: Dict[str, str] = {"Cookie": cookie_value}

response: Response = httpx.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Found this out by reading the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-user-identities#access-user-claims-using-the-api) & looking at the network call in the browser:

[image: network-in-browser]

**Edit**: Please note that in some cases the cookie can consist of several cookies, e.g. `AppServiceAuthSession` & `AppServiceAuthSession1`. You need to include them both in the header `cookie` in your request.
For example
`{"cookie": "AppServiceAuthSession=abc;AppServiceAuthSession1=def"}`