# get azure ad login username in php

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to get username when I logged in Azure ad. When I go https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net it redirect to azure ad. After that I want to use, that username. But I dont know how to do it? Below code didnt work.

I also wrote https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback but didnt work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $.get("https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me", function (data, status) {
                for (var key in data[0]["user_claims"]) {
                    var obj = data[0]["user_claims"][key];
                    alert(obj["typ"]);   //claim type in user_claims
                    alert(obj["val"])    //claim value in user_claims                 
                }
            });
        });
   </script>
```

Comment: Please share details of error/output you are getting?How you are implementing autentication?

Comment: Hi @newuser, Please reply to above comment if you are still looking for help?

Answer (score 0):

Actually we can only do `https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` when we did nothing with AAD information in our project.
[image]

If you integrate AAD in your project already, you can modify your code getting auth information in the backend, and show them in your client.

There is a issue similar to yours, you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59550817/permission-error-for-azure-active-directory-easy-auth-auth-me-returns-401).