# Flask default http headers - Caching and more

Tags: flask, http-headers

I'm inquiring on Flask and was wondering what are the default values for things such as cache-control. I can't find information on any HTTP headers. Maybe I'm mistaken and it's the server software who takes care of this part.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question about Caching:
As Flask docs state

> Flask itself does not provide caching for you, but Flask-Caching, an extension for Flask does.

So you can use [Flask-Caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if you want to do caching for your website.

For your second question about http headers:
You can use `request` object to get different header values [How to get http headers in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386995/how-to-get-http-headers-in-flask) and use [make_response](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response) to set custom headers.

Comment: I thought Flask-caching was for server-side caching only. Not for instruction on caching for clients.

Comment: Maybe, actually I am not very good at caching topic and never tried it. So am not sure how exactly you can do it on client side.