# How can i access the log of visited user agents in flask?

Tags: python, flask

Sorry,  for the question if it doesn't make any sense. I am a self-learner and don't have many resources. I have searched on google a lot of times.

I was trying to access the User-Agent log in flask, is there any log where all the user-agents visited logs.

I need to get the visit count of each user agent.

How do I can get the user agents visited as an object in flask, it is to be listed in a table in view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878020/how-do-i-get-the-user-agent-with-flask

Comment: if you runs on www server Apache/nginx then it may save all requests in its logs and it may have information about `User-Agent` in log.