# How to get the user agent in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

How to get the user agent in Flask?
Explain by code
How to get the user agent in Flask?" - by using Python web framework used for building web applications. When users access web pages through their browsers, the browser sends various pieces of information to the server as part of the HTTP request headers. One of these headers is called the "User-Agent" header, which contains details about the user's browser, operating system, and device.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the user agent with Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878020/how-do-i-get-the-user-agent-with-flask)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use flask.Request object to get header User-Agent in the following

```
from flask import request

def endpoint():
    user_agent = request.headers.get("user-agent")
    ...
```